# regular System Crash

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, ssh, system, crash

I installed a new Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC. And I have set swap. The system will crash about each 2 hours. When the system crashes, mouse and keyboard do not work even the Ctrl + alt + f*. Firstly I thought that it is KDE crash, but when I try to remote connect the system via ssh, I cannot succeed either. I checked /var/log/syslog. The log when crashed is some unprintable character, just as follows:

```
Aug 29 14:25:14 gaoxiang avahi-daemon[745]: Invalid response packet from host fe80::c065:7b47:c0e4:f6fd. \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00‌​\00 
Aug 29 14:28:46 gaoxiang rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="805" x-info="rsyslog.com"] start 
Aug 29 14:28:46 gaoxiang rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104 
Aug 29 14:28:46 gaoxiang rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
```

So, I want to ask what happened in this situation, and how can I fix it.
I have ever try ubuntu 14.04, which contains the same problem. My PC is dell optiplex 990.

Comment: Have you checked the system log for errors? Could you help us help you by [edit]ing your question to include them? Thank you.

Comment: yes, I checked /var/log/syslog. The log when crashed is some unprintable charactor, just as follows:

Aug 29 14:25:14 gaoxiang avahi-daemon[745]: Invalid response packet from host fe80::c065:7b47:c0e4:f6fd.
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Aug 29 14:28:46 gaoxiang rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="805" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Aug 29 14:28:46 gaoxiang rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104
Aug 29 14:28:46 gaoxiang rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101

Comment: Please [edit] that comment into your question. Comments can be deleted for a number of reasons and might not be read.

Comment: Do you have a cron job running every 2 hours perhaps? [edit] that info into your question as well. When in doubt review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you very much. I donot have any cron job running every 2 hours. Usually, when I open some web page, or some software, this crash can happens.

Comment: I would assume a web page based on the IPv6 address in Invalid response packet from host fe80::c065:7b47:c0e4:f6fd

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/774766/what-could-cause-a-system-reboot-after-1-2-hours-uptime

Comment: Related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/940030

Answer (score 1):

Hard crashes often show hardware problems. Start with memory test (memtest86+), it may crash on you if there is CPU or mainboard problem pretty fast. If it goes well (let it run for 2-3 hours!) then check harddisk smart data as hdd errors may be related to such crashes. But nearly every hardware problem may cause it, from USB problems to ... anything, really.

Don't expect to get specific answers, though.

Comment: Further info may result in specific answers.

Comment: yes, I have thought that it is hardware problem. But when I use windows in this PC, there is no crash problem.